# How do I implement CREATE and READ requests in PHP for Backbone?

Tags: php, backbone.js

My quick solution was as such:

```
private function receive()
{
    if(isset($_GET))
    {
        return $_GET;
    }
    return json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
}
```

CREATE and READ requests in Backbone are implemented as POST and GET ajax calls.

I can receive POST and GET ajax calls using my method called `receive()` which will return an object.

I found this too simple.  Is there something I'm missing perhaps?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: The purpose of CREATE (POST) and READ (GET) is, as implied in their name, to create and get resources from the server. You should probably do something with the `$_GET` and `$_POST` parameters (with `$_GET`: fetch some data from a database, fetch a remote resource from an API, read a file..., or with `$_POST`: persist data in a database, post to a remote API, write to a file...).

Comment: Not really essentially the beauty of a RESTful app is that all Backbone cares about is either a json response, or a http code and an empty response in some cases. How you implement that in the backend is up to you, have a search for "php rest api framework" and see what you fancy. As for when to us GET/POST/PUT and DELETE that is well documented :)